# rosdep get list of packages for dependencies

Tags: ros2, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tl;dr: How do I get the list of packages that would be installed by `rosdep install` without actually installing them?

I want to create a rootfs that can be used to (cross-)compile ROS2. Instead of setting up the ROS repo and running rosdep within the rootfs, I want to gather the dependencies as a list of deb packages outside of the rootfs and only install the list of deb packages that are returned by rosdep.
I.e. I do not want to run `rosdep install` inside the rootfs, but rather want it to return the list of packages it would install and use this list in `apt install <list>`

Running:

```
rosdep keys --from-path src --ignore-packages-from-source --os debian:stretch --rosdistro=crystal
```

seems to include dependencies that are part of the workspace, although `--ignore-packages-from-source` is provided. E.g. in a ROS2 base workspace from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/release-latest/ros2.repos, rosdep keys will provide a list that contains `rclcpp`, `rclpy`, `launch`, `std_msgs`. Hence, piping this into `rosdep resolve`:

```
rosdep keys --from-path src -i --os debian:stretch --rosdistro=crystal | xargs rosdep resolve
```

will not provide the correct list because of  `ERROR: no rosdep rule for 'std_msgs'`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321431/rosdep-get-list-of-packages-for-dependencies/) by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2019-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You want `--reinstall` to avoid having to uninstall the packages first.

You just need to tell the second instance of rosdep that it's also resolving for your rosdistro of choice.

```
rosdep keys --rosdistro crystal --from-path ~/workspace --ignore-src | xargs rosdep resolve --rosdistro crystal
```

Another approach is

```
rosdep install --reinstall --simulate --from-path ~/work/diux/sitl_gazebo/ --ignore-src | awk '{print $5 }'
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Christian Rauch](https://answers.ros.org/users/28941/christian-rauch/) on 2019-04-18**:
The second option (via `--simulate`) solved my problem:

```
rosdep install --reinstall --simulate --from-path src --ignore-src --os debian:stretch --rosdistro=crystal --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 libopensplice69 rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers python3-lark-parser" | awk '{print $5 }'
```

gives me a list of packages.

The first option via `rosdep keys` still tries to resolve packages that are part of the workspace, even after setting the target OS and ROS distro for fetching the keys and resolving them. E.g.:

```
rosdep keys --from-path src --ignore-packages-from-source --os debian:stretch --rosdistro=crystal | xargs rosdep resolve --os debian:stretch --rosdistro=crystal
```

still results in: `ERROR: No definition of [ament_lint_common] for OS [debian]`, which is part of `ament_lint`.